# xen and libvirt bridge configuration

Tags: xen, bridge, libvirt

I have a Centos 5.5 server with Xen 3.2 and libvirt for virt-manager installed. Before installed libvirt I have the bridge configuration just like the documentation on Xen says:

xenbr0, eth0 and peth0 interfaces.

After installed libvirt my configuration got:

eth0, peth0 and virbr0

So the virbr0 was added instead of xenbr0, I read the documentation and this is a NAT adaptor for libvirt. So in order to get a bridge adaptor I got this guide:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on-centos-6.2-with-bridged-networking

But my peth0 is still up so I presume that xen bridge is still up. Can someone explain me how to proper setup a bridge network interface with Xen and libvirt because with the guide I followed I got a new adaptor called br0 which is the bridge but it has the same MAC address of my eth0 NIC.

I will apreciate any help.

Comment: in case someone needs help with this, first read this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/42438/xen-network-bridge-interface-renaming - on the comments say you should use OS native bridging, and in order to disable xen bridge you can use: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that bridge in the `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` file.

Look at the line starting with `(network-script`. For full options of the xen-bridges look at `/etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge`.

In your case "bridge= and netdev=" should be sufficient.

But this should only be used if you have only one bridge.
For anything else it is recommended to use OS-level configurations.

For a very complex setup with bonds, vlan-trunks and more than 4 bridges I wrote my own init-script on SLES10 - since the OS-level configuration files were not able to do what I wanted.

On more current OSes this should be (almost) no problem.

Comment: Do you have any special ip route setup on the dom0 to allow that the virtual machines can see each other on the same network? I am having trouble with this.

Comment: @mongaru no - nothing special. Check if you have firewalls enabled either on Dom0 or on the DomUs...